# Create Custom Numbering Format Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I need to create a formula or custom numbering format that references the Requirement Type returns the requirement ID FR,SC, Etc and numbers the column FR001, FR002, FR003... or for SC001, SC002, SC003... for all of the requirements.

How is this possible?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my example I created one table for the codes (insert > table) and one for your requirments. To make the formula less complicated I added a helper column for the code which uses a Index/match formula to retrieve the code based on the type. Within the ID column CountIf is used to get the "running" number".

Code `=INDEX(tblCodes[Requirement],MATCH([@Type],tblCodes[RequirementType],0))`

ID `=[@Code] & TEXT( COUNTIF($E$3:$E3,[@Code])+1,"000")`

[image]

Comment: So I have the table above on 1 sheet and then a list of requirements on another.

Comment: No problem - the formulas will work with two sheets. I used this approach because it is easier to visualize for the answer

Comment: This works! Thank you However my numbering is starting at 002

Comment: I am not sure: your are expecting 001 as first number but instead get 002? If so, did you check the ID-Formula: what is $E$3 might refer to a different row than you use to start with the requirements

Comment: =[@Code] & TEXT( COUNTIF($B$5:$B5,[@Code])+1,"000")

Comment: hmmm - difficult - can you upload a screenshot of the requirements table?

Comment: added a -1 and it worked very odd